# Retrieving time without NTP on IoT core

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

I have an interesting issue. The university I am working at does not allow NTP packets to go through their network, so the basic timing of the Raspberry pi's is completely off, making a connection or ping to them impossible. Is there any work around through the command line on the windows 10 IoT core that I could use to set the time and date? When I try to hard set the date as "date 05/12/2018" the command line returns 'A required privilege is not held by the client'. 
Any ideas?

Comment: have the RPi go here to get the current time ... https://time.is/

Comment: Use htpdate. It picks the time from a website like Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you must use `-` instead of `/` for the date command. Also make sure you are doing it from an SSH connection. Finally, there is a built-in time service in Windows that can access NTP or domain controllers in a LAN. See this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dccf1344-0f6c-4de6-87bc-1a1a65eb1582/synchronizing-time-with-external-source-on-2088-r2?forum=winservergen) for more info.